# Custom Validation on group of checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to understand how I can validate a group of checkboxes.

My Model:

```
[MinSelected(MinSelected = 1)]
public IList<CheckList> MealsServed { get; set; }
```

I'd like to be able to create a custom validator that will ensure that at least 1 (or some other number) checkbox is selected. If not, display an `ErrorMessage`.

```
#region Validators

public class MinSelectedAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int MinSelected { get; set; }

    // what do I need to do here?
}
```

Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could override the [IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679289.aspx) method and ensure that the collection contains at least `MinSelected` items with `IsChecked` equal to `true` (I suppose that this `CheckList` class of yours has an `IsChecked` property):

```
public class MinSelectedAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int MinSelected { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var instance = value as IList<CheckList>;
        if (instance != null)
        {
            // make sure that you have at least MinSelected
            // IsChecked values equal to true inside the IList<CheckList>
            // collection for the model to be valid
            return instance.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Count() >= MinSelected;
        }
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```