# 'Required' Data annotation not working on a group of checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, validation, mvc-editor-templates

My problem is somewhat similar to this problem [Custom Validation on group of checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661418/custom-validation-on-group-of-checkboxes)

I have a group of check boxes in the view (New.cshtml) which are rendered using 'ParentObject' as a view model

ParentObject.cs :-

```
public class ParentObject
{

  [Required]
  public IEnumerable<RegionObject> Regions { get; set; }

}
```

New.cshtml :-

```
@model ParentObject

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()){   
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Regions)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Regions)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Regions)
<input type="submit" title="Create new parent object" class="button btn67" value="Create" />
}
```

The editor template for regions is in \Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\RegionObject.cshtml
which is like this

```
@model RegionObject
<p>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Code)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
</p>
```

The RegionObject view model is :

```
public class RegionObject
{
   public Guid Code { get; set; }
   public string Name  { get; set; }
   public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Why is the 'Required' data annotation on 'Regions' not working? I want to make sure at least 1 check box is selected against Regions. I would have thought 'Required' would do the job but apparently not. Do I need to write a custom validator to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Required attribute cannot operate on collections as you might wish. Also how do you expect it to know that at least one checkbox need to be selected from this `RegionObject` custom class? How do you expect it to relate the `IsChecked` property in this collection?

> Do I need to write a custom validator to make this work?

Yes, you need a custom validation attribute to achieve that. For example:

```
public class AtLeastOneRegionMustBeCheckedAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var instance = value as IEnumerable<RegionObject>;
        if (instance != null)
        {
            return instance.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Count() > 0;
        }
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }    
}
```

and then:

```
public class ParentObject
{
    [AtLeastOneRegionMustBeChecked(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one region")]
    public IEnumerable<RegionObject> Regions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been asking to myself as to how it would understand the business rule that atleast 1 region was selected. I spent time making this work using Self validating model and using custom validating attribute didn't occur to me. Thanks for your help.